# Should I use more than one og:type on my website?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta

There're a blog and a gallery sections on my website. Should I use different OpenGraph types for each page, or only one, `website` for all pages? I don't really know what it affects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one could help me, I haven't found anything about it, and I see no reason why Facebook wouldn't accept two or more og:types from one website, I'll use both in the future.